# Toggle drop down by clicking caret in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to have the drop down top link to another web page and then toggle the drop down by clicking the caret next to the drop down text?

```
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="disabled" href="http://google.com">
                        Dropdown <b class="caret dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></b>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Is it possible for one to call the data-toggle="dropdown" function from  tag?

Comment: What? you want the link to go to www.google.com then toggle down the menu?!?!?!

Comment: The link should go to www.google.com, but I want to be able to click on the caret and toggle the dropdown if possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xwetvL3y/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to move the caret outside of the google linked anchor:

```
  <a class="disabled" href="http://google.com">Dropdown</a>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwetvL3y/2/

Comment: yes that's what I'm after, but when I try it this way I cannot get the two links to align properly.

Comment: Well that is a whole other question then, it works in the fiddle right?